# Ignore LINE BREAK

Tags: php

I have a code which I extracted from a text file. Every character in the text file have been embedded into array including line breaks. I want to ignore the line breaks. I've tried so many ways but it fails.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code where you read the file?

Comment: Second what blorgbeard has said... depending on how you read the file, you can probably tell the reader to strip out the line breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you have an array of lines ending with `\n`, you can remove them like so...

```
$line = rtrim($line, "\n");
```

Comment: i did it. thanks! i used trim before dont even realise this kind of function exist :))

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
str_replace("\n", "", $text);
```

..?

http://ideone.com/rpQCq

Comment: You might need to replace \r as well (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php Example #2)